# Dynamically check radio-button after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

the problem I have in my application is that when I load the following webpage, only the last radiobutton set is checked, while I want all of them checked.

```
    for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++){
    if(results.rows.item(i).qst_status==0)      //OK
        var x="<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-inline='true' data-type='horizontal'><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-1' value='OK' checked='checked' onclick='okpressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-1' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ok.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-2' value='KO' onclick='kopressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-2' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ko.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-3' value='NA' onclick='napressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-3' style='width: 100px; height:43px;'>N.A.</label></fieldset>";
    else if(results.rows.item(i).qst_status==1) //KO
        var x="<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-inline='true' data-type='horizontal'><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-1' value='OK' onclick='okpressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-1' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ok.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-2' value='KO' checked='checked' onclick='kopressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-2' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ko.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-3' value='NA' onclick='napressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-3' style='width: 100px; height:43px;'>N.A.</label></fieldset>";
    else if(results.rows.item(i).qst_status==2) //NA
        var x="<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-inline='true' data-type='horizontal'><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-1' value='OK' onclick='okpressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-1' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ok.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-2' value='KO' onclick='kopressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-2' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ko.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-3' value='NA' checked='checked' onclick='napressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-3' style='width: 100px; height:43px;'>N.A.</label></fieldset>";
    else                                        //Audit not completed
        var x="<fieldset data-role='controlgroup' data-inline='true' data-type='horizontal'><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-1' value='OK' onclick='okpressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-1' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ok.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-2' value='KO' onclick='kopressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-2' style='width: 100px;'><img src='images/ko.png'></img></label><input type='radio' name='radio-choice' id='radio-choice-3' value='NA' onclick='napressed("+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+");'/><label for='radio-choice-3' style='width: 100px; height:43px;'>N.A.</label></fieldset>";
    if(adt_status=="completed"){            //Audit completed
        if(results.rows.item(i).chk_att==1) //Attachments
            var v="<td width='10%' align='right'><a href='cameraroll.html' rel='external' onclick='updID("+results.rows.item(i).chk_id+");'><img src='images/ico/attach.png'></img></a></td>";
        else                                //No attachments
            var v="<td width='10%'></td>";
    }
    else{                                   //Audit not completed
        if(results.rows.item(i).chk_att==1) //Ci sono allegati
            var v="<td width='10%' align='right'><a href='#mediapopup' data-rel='popup' onclick='updID("+results.rows.item(i).chk_id+");'><img src='images/ico/attach.png'></img></a></td>";
        else                                //No attachments
            var v="<td width='10%' align='right'><a href='#mediapopup_noall' data-rel='popup' onclick='updID("+results.rows.item(i).chk_id+");'><img src='images/ico/attach.png'></img></a></td>";
    }
    t=t+"<tr><td colspan='2' width='90%'><p>"+results.rows.item(i).qst_sent+"</p></td><td width='10%' align='center'><a href='#notepopup' data-role='button' data-icon='info' data-rel='popup' onclick='updNote(\""+results.rows.item(i).qst_help+"\");' data-transition='pop' data-iconpos='notext'></a></td></tr><tr><td width='45%'>"+x+"</td><td width='45%'><textarea style='height:50px; width:100%' id='note' name='note' placeholder='Insert here notes' onchange='checkNote(this.value, "+results.rows.item(i).qst_id+")'>"+results.rows.item(i).qst_note+"</textarea></td>"+v+"</tr><tr><td colspan='3'><hr></td></tr>";
    }
$("#checklisttable").append(t).trigger('create');
```

If I trigger inside the for cycle, everything is ok but it takes much more time (about 100 seconds against 10 seconds if I put the trigger outside the cycle).
How can I solve it?

Comment: Just an FYI, you should assign `id`s to only one element. If you wish to assign the same `id` to multiple elements, use a class instead.

Comment: They way radio buttons work is that they can't be all checked if they have the same name.

Comment: `$('[type=radio]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh'); });` this will go through all radio buttons and check them. However, only one radio in each group will be checked.

Comment: Well, radio button behaviour is that only one can be checked inside same group (same attr name). So, you want to use checkbox maybe or degroup your radio buttons

Comment: Can you post your final HTML result? Basically I want to see javascript HTML output.

Comment: I changed the way the ID are assigned, so now I have id='ok"+i+"', id='ko""+i+"' and id='na"+i+"'. All IDs are different but the problem persists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working DEMO here, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/dzckn/

First, you need to change the radio button property to 'checked', then, changed the UI to checked UI. Otherwise, the UI won't change even though the checked box is checked.

You can check/uncheck and see the checked value.

## HTML

```
<form id="checklisttable">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Vertical:</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a">
                <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
                <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
                <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2d" id="checkbox-v-2d">
                <label for="checkbox-v-2d">Four</label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#checklisttable input").each(function(){            
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });

    $("#checklisttable label").addClass('ui-checkbox-on').removeClass('ui-checkbox-off');
    $("#checklisttable span.ui-icon").addClass('ui-icon-checkbox-on').removeClass('ui-icon-checkbox-off');
});
```